# What species is this dark green shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I love this bush! It is 45 inches tall and has 1 inch long leaves. I'd like to plant more of them, but I have no idea what species it is! It's thriving in New Jersey and is 3 years old or more.

[image: bush]
[image: bush_pic2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like another *Spiraea*, and I suspect it's *Spiraea arguta*, but without seeing flowers it's hard to be certain it's that, might also be *Spiraea nipponica*. Both have an arching growth habit with white flowers, but arranged differently - this link, although it's a sales site, has some good photos of different varieties of *Spiraea* and accompanying descriptions of growth habit, height and spread and so on https://www.scotplantsdirect.co.uk/plants/garden/spiraea. If you prune this now or later in the season, (assuming you are in the northern hemisphere) you will be removing the growths that will flower next spring, so if you've not seen any flowers on it, perhaps you've been cutting it back at the wrong time. If you've had no flowers, don't prune this year, prune immediately after flowering next year.

Comment: Thanks very much!